# Update php version 7 on server its hows fatal error on symonfy2`

Tags: php-7, symfony-2.8

request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error: Cannot use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Null as Null because 'Null' is a special class name" at /vol/vhost/utterprints.com/src/Design/AppBundle/Controller/OrdersController.php line 30 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Compile Error: Cannot use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Null as Null because 'Null' is a special class name at /vol/vhost/utterprints.com/src/Design/AppBundle/Controller/OrdersController.php:30)"} []

IN ordersController on line 30 this validator component is use.

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with PHP 7.0 the "null" keyword becomes a reserved word in a sense that it cannot be used as a name of class, trait, interface nor a part of namespace.

I see that Symfony [has support for PHP7](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-achieves-100-php7-compatibility) since August 2015, so you may need to update your Symfony installation.